# Theorem 3, Section 2.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing, definition

In [this](https://youtu.be/NpSKwx12tkk) lecture, professor Artem Chernikov, define linear combination as, $v\in V$ is linear combination of $S$ if $v= a_1\cdot u_1+…+a_n \cdot u_n$ ; $a_i\in F$, $\forall i\in J_n$ and $u_i\in S$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Hoffman used the term, $v$ is linear combination of vectors in $S$. Both definition don’t sound same. I guess, former definition refers to value $v$ and latter definition refers to expression. I’m feeling confused.

IMO, Hoffman definition of span is not “coherent” with theorem 3 section 2.2. Hoffman definition of span makes span immediately subspace, by theorem 2 section 2.2, but don’t really tell anything else. I mean, if we use Hoffman definition of span, i.e $\mathrm{span}(S)=\bigcap_{W\in \Omega}W$ ; $\Omega=\{W\subseteq V|W\leq V$ and $S\subseteq W\}$, then it is natural to show $\mathrm{span}(S)$$=\bigcap_{W\in \Omega}W$$=\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot u_i|n\in \Bbb{N}, a_i\in F, u_i\in S\}$ by basic set theory. **Question:** How to show $\bigcap_{W\in \Omega}W \subseteq \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot u_i|n\in \Bbb{N}, a_i\in F, u_i\in S\} $ inclusion? Let $x\in W$, $\forall W\in \Omega$. **How to write $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot u_i$?**

That’s why I like, span$(S)= \{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot u_i|n\in \Bbb{N}, a_i\in F, u_i\in S\}=\{v\in V|v$ is linear combination of $S\}$ definition, as given [here](https://youtu.be/NpSKwx12tkk). Then we prove the following:

> **(a)** span$(S)$ is subspace of $V$ and $S\subseteq \mathrm{span}(S)$.
>
> **(b)** If $W\leq V$ such that $S\subseteq W$, then span$(S)\subseteq W$.

**My attempt:** (a) To show span$(S)\leq V$, we need to check 3 condition, (1) Since $S\neq \emptyset$, $\exists s\in S$. So $0_V=0_F \cdot s\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. (2) Let $v_1, v_2\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Then $v_1=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i \cdot p_i$ and $v_2=\sum_{i\in J_m} b_i\cdot q_i$. So $v_1+v_2= (\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i \cdot p_i) + (\sum_{i\in J_m} b_i\cdot q_i)=a_1\cdot p_1 +…+a_n \cdot p_n+ b_1\cdot q_1+…+b_n\cdot q_n\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Hence span$(S)$ is closed under addition. (3) Let $c\in F$ and $v\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Then $v=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot u_i$. By multiplication and distributive axiom of vector space, $c\cdot v=c\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot u_i)$$=\sum_{i=1}^nc\cdot (a_i \cdot x_i)$$=\sum_{i=1}^n (c\cdot_{F}a_i)\cdot u_i \in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Hence span$(S)$ is closed under scalar multiplication. Thus span$(S)\leq V$. It’s easy to check $S\subseteq \mathrm{span}(S)$, $s=1_F \cdot s\in \mathrm{span}(S)$, $\forall s\in S$. Thus $S\subseteq \mathrm{span}(S)$.

(b) Let $x\in \mathrm{span}(S)$. Then $x=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot u_i$ ; $a_i \in  F$, $u_i\in S$. Since $S\subseteq W$ and $W\leq V$, we have $a_i\cdot u_i\in W$, $\forall i \in J_n$. By definition of subspace, $x=a_1\cdot u_1+…+a_n\cdot u_n\in W$. Hence span$(S)\subseteq W$. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: What's the disagreement? $v$ is a linear combination of vectors in $S$ and $v$ is a linear combination of $S$ are slightly different ways of saying the same thing. The latter phrasing is a touch odd, I'd prefer "$v$ is in the span of $S$", but it's all the same

Comment: @FShrike idk either what’s the disagreement. I just don’t know the definition. I was clarifying definition of linear combination. Excuse my stupid question. I’m new in linear algebra.

Comment: Ah I see now, you're trying to demonstrate that the span is the minimal containing subspace

Comment: It's very hard for anyone who doesn't have a copy of Hoffman at their side to answer this question. Can you quote the theorems you are referring to?

Comment: @FShrike yup. And which book did use for linear algebra? Don’t tell me only SE.

Comment: @user264745 : ) I'm afraid I'm going to have to disappoint you. I've never studied lin. alg. out of a textbook - a year ago, I spent three-four months of my summer break, part-time, learning linear algebra from SE and various scattered online sources (a lot of YT...) no textbooks!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The subspace spanned by a non empty set $S$ of a vector space $V$ is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$.

Comment: @FShrike respect+

Comment: Thanks. Your proof is fine, anyway. The definition as the minimal containing subspace is a little odd, I suppose it becomes more useful in the setting of infinite dimensional linear spaces. The set of all finite linear combinations is nicer though imo

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for reviewing my attempt. Yup that’s what(why finite linear combinations is nicer) I try to justify in my second paragraph.

Comment: @FShrike I’m sorry to bother you again. I read definition of linear dependent. It’s relatively long definition. I rephrased it in the following way: $S\subseteq V$ is called lin dep if $\exists u_1,…,u_n\in S$, $\exists a_1,…,a_n\in F$ such that $u_i\neq u_j$, if $i\neq j$ and $A_i\neq 0$, for some $i\in J_n$ and $a_1\cdot u_1+…+a_n\cdot u_n=0_V$. Is my rephrasing precise?

Comment: @user264745 No worries at all, no bother. I deleted my previous half answer because the only I could see to extract a combination for $x$ used a proof by contradiction... involving the argument $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is a subspace, so, not what you wanted. Your rephrasing is precise yeah, if being very formal you’d want to explain what all the letters denoted (but this is obvious from context for me). I like to think of it as “there is a vector $u\in S$ such that $\operatorname{span}(u)\subseteq\operatorname{span}(S\setminus\{u\})$” which is a very compact definition of dependence.

Comment: @FShrike I’m sorry for late reply. I was thinking about this post to offer bounty because I’m curious for solution. Then I saw your comment without my reply. **Claim:** $S$ is dependent iff $\exists u\in S$ such that span$(u)\subseteq$span$(S-\{u\})$. **Proof:** first of all $S\neq \emptyset$, since $\emptyset$ is independent. ($\Leftarrow$)suppose $\exists u\in S$ s.t span$(u)\subseteq$span$(S-\{u\})$. Then $u=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot u_i$ ; $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $a_i\in F$, $u\in S-\{u\}$. So $1_F\cdot u -a_1\cdot u_1-…-a_n\cdot u_n=0_V$, $u\neq u_i$, $\forall i\in J_n$ and $1_F\neq 0_F$.

Comment: Thus $S$ is dependent. $(\Rightarrow$) $\exists u_1,…,u_n\in S$, $a_1,…,a_n\in F$ s.t $u_i\neq u_j$ if $i\neq j$, $a_i\neq 0_F$ for some $i\in J_n$ and $\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot u_i=0_V$. Let $a_j\neq 0_F$ for some $j\in J_n$. Then $u_j= \sum_{i\in J_n-\{j\}}(a^{-1}_j-a_i)\cdot u_i$. So $u_j\in \mathrm{span}(S-\{u_j\})$. Let $x\in \mathrm{span}(u_j)$. Then $x=b\cdot u_j$. So $x= \sum_{i\in J_n-\{j\}}(b a^{-1}_j-a_i)\cdot u_i \in \mathrm{span}(S-\{u_j\})$. Our desired result. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: @user264745 Your proof is correct although I think you meant to say: $$u_j=-a_j^{-1}\sum_{i=1\\i\neq j}a_iu_i$$

Comment: @FShrike yup. That is also fine. I should have written it as $-(a^{-1}_j a_i)$ or $-(\frac{a_i}{a_j})$, by elementary property of fields.

Comment: @FShrike I think we don’t need stronger condition $\mathrm{span}(u)\subseteq \mathrm{span}(S-\{u\})$. $u\in \mathrm{span}(S-\{u\})$ works out just fine.

Comment: The conditions should actually be equivalent if I’m not mistaken

Comment: @FShrike Ohhh! Yes they are equivalent, my bad.